# Open a popup automatically and prevent browser to block it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, event-handling, dom-events

I need to call a function (which one will open a popup) when my page is loading.

If I want the popup to be open, the function should be called by a user event (a click or something).

I tried to simulate the `click` event but it's not isn't working. The function is being called but no `click` event has been created.

For example, I tried with angular to do the following:

```
var element = angular.element("<div ng-click='MyFunction()'></div>");
            compiled = $compile(element)(scope);
            $timeout(function () {
                compiled.triggerHandler('click');
            }, 100)
```

Comment: what are you expecting to happen? please clarify

Comment: Two questions: Why are using a trigger handler with a `$timeout` if you wish to catch a user event, & why are you creating the element with `angular.element` instead of placing this into the root template that is first loaded?

Comment: I don't want to catch a user event since there is no user event.I want to simulate a user event: `triggerHandler`.
I need the `$timeout` for other reasons

Comment: @AminJafari: i would like to simulate a user event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@IsraGab,when you want an user event when page loads then i think you must go for onmouseout Event for body element.
here is `plunker` link:
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4BhjwnxOnVHCwC2DhiCk?p=preview)